# Kafka consumer groups behavioral unequally

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Trying to understand the consumer group Behavioral  in Kafka. Example  4 partitions are available . In consumer side , Consumer group is holding the 4 consumers . In this scenario among 4 consumers in consumer group only one consumer always getting the message . Others are idle always. what are the possible reason for this ?

Is it All partitions are holding the same message ? or 
it it all partitions are having the equal message ? or 
can we consider the partitions are not being distributed equally ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Others are idle always. what are the possible reason for this ?

By default, this is not possible with 4 partitions and 4 consumers. You would have to manually assign all 4 consumers in the group to a single topic-partition. Or there is just no data in the partitions for which those consumers are assigned, so they "appear" idle, but they are still polling 0 records.

> Is it All partitions are holding the same message ?

A message contains a key and value. If your key is null, then it is possible for the same value of a message to exist on more than one partition. If you have non-null keys, then it is not possible for the same message (same key) to be on different partitions with the DefaultPartitioner.

> or it it all partitions are having the equal message ?

No. Primarly because even just timestamps and offsets do not match over more than one partition

> can we consider the partitions are not being distributed equally ?

If you have your own partitioner, or non-null keys, then it is possible to create "hot" / "fat" partitions in which it'll be unbalanced from others. With null keys, then the producer is round-robined over all partitions evenly.